# How can I make Solr follow links while parsing a "Solr XML" file to index the results?

Tags: xml, solr, xml-parsing, lucidworks

There is a web-accessible file system of thousands and thousands of PDF files that I need to be indexed by Solr (with Lucidworks).

I have an XML file containing data corresponding to each. The XML contains the ID, some simple metadata, and the URL of its corresponding PDF in the file system.

Currently, I am able to format the XML in such a way that Solr reads it and indexes all the metadata I need, including the URL of the PDF.

I would like Solr to, as it's parsing the files, actually follow the URL and index the referenced PDF data along with the XML-supplied metadata. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet (on pure Solr), would probably be a DataImportHandler with nested entities.

The external processor would be [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor) and within that, you can put [TikaEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor) with appropriate data source. Use the variables to construct/pass URL to the inner entity.

Remember to mark the outer (XPath) entity as rootEntity=false to ensure that Solr documents are created for the inner entities.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much. I'll read up on this. I'm going to a Solr training next week, so that sounds like it will help me. Is there a non-"Pure Solr" method of doing this that'd be easier? Another question: if "rootEntity=true" does the fulltext of the parsed PDF become part of the document that referenced it? Because I think that's what I want instead.

Comment: You can always parse your xml files outside of Solr in your language of choice and use the appropriate Solr Client/Langauge Binding - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr to update the index. I tend to do this more often than using he DataImportHandler.

Comment: Root entity should be the one that you want Solr to store. So, if you have some XML metadata and some PDF references, you have XML as rootEntity=true (or more-specifically any entities above XML one as rootEntity=false). Just be careful if you have multiple PDFs in one XML, because they will all map into the same field spaces. Other options include writing your custom Transformer that get PDFs and inject them that way. Or writing SolrJ client that does everything outside. There is always more than one way to do it.